# Can CsvHelper deal with data like "[[0,0],[100,100]]"？

Tags: csvhelper

I want to deal with data like `[[0,0],[100,100]]`,but I don't know how to use `CsvHelper` do this.  I define like  `float[][]` and `CsvReader` return null, so what is the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

This data is not csv. CsvHelper would try to parse it like `"[[0"`, `"0]"`, `"[100"`, `"100]]"` You can use the `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget package to deserialize it.

```cs
var data = "[[0,0],[100,100]]";

float[][] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<float[][]>(data);
```

@John makes a good point. This could be data inside a cell in a CSV file. In which case a `ClassMap` might be a good choice.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,Data");
            writer.WriteLine("1,\"[[0,0],[100,100]]\"");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();

            var results = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }  
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float[][] Data { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Data).ConvertUsing(row => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<float[][]>(row.GetField("Data")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if it's a cell in a CSV file, then `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<float[][]>(csv.GetField("MyField"))`, where you have CsvHelper keep the data as a string